# Conda stuck on Executing Transaction

Tags: python, conda, plotly-dash

I have Windows 7 Enterprise machine on the network at work. I installed the Conda version 4.5.4. Installing pandas, openpyxl, went smoothly. But soon after trying to install Dash, Conda was stuck on 'Executing Transaction'. I tried a different package and same thing. I then proceeded to install Conda 4.5.5 and that successfully installed. So when I went back to installing Dash, it went back to being stuck on 'Executing Transaction'.

Any suggestions as to what the root cause would be?

**Update:**
Nor reply needed. I just deleted my existing environment, then created a new environment. I installed Dash as the first package and this time it installed, but it took 15 minutes if not longer.

Comment: When you run spyder or when you type `conda list` or `activate your_env_name` do you get any weird behavior like inserting empty rows in spyder or taking too long to run in the anaconda prompt? I am facing those issues along with conda getting stuck.

Comment: Do you get very slow response times in conda regarding other actions? I am having the exactly same issue `Executing transaction: /` for a couple of minutes. Not even mention the time it takes to run `conda list` within the environment, takes 4-5 mins easily. I am running on Windows 10. Maybe you found a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: This is old now, but if it is sill problematic then run installation command with some verbosity flags (`-vv`) and try to identify the bottleneck. Possibly a post-link installation script.