# Anaconda prompt stuck at "Executing Transaction"

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

I'm relatively new to Python and using an anaconda 3  installation on a Windows 10 machine. I've never used the Anaconda prompt beyond conda installing a few packages and 
`conda update --all`.
Today I used the latter statement again, but the prompt is stuck at 
`Executing Transaction: \` 
with the backslash going around in circles for the past hour. Please suggest what I can do. 
 I checked this link but it seems to be specific to Dash, which wasn't in the list of libraries to be updated/installed.
[Conda stuck on Executing Transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51273588/conda-stuck-on-executing-transaction)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run anaconda prompt as Administrator, this will resolve your problem..